# Determine if a 3D element in WPF is too far away to be seen

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, projection

This WPF based sim is using per-frame animation to (re)position elements as conditions change. Some elements are in the field-of-view but are so far away as to no longer be visible. I’d like to detect this condition and modify the element so that a visual indicator remains present, even though the element is too far away to be seen. Determining that an element has reached a pixel size threshold in the Viewport3D might be a way to do this.

Is there a way within the WPF system to determine the XY coordinates in the Viewport3D to which a coordinate in the 3D Coordinate Space will be projected?

It would be possible, it seems, to code the 3D to 2D projection calculation outside of WPF. But since WPF is already doing that maybe there is way to tap into that.

Comment: Came across a pretty good answer here: [Projecting a 3D point to a 2D screen coordinate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519106/projecting-a-3d-point-to-a-2d-screen-coordinate) TY!

Answer (score 0):

I think a way to go would be to compute the bounding sphere of the object.
(there are some code out there to do so, it's not hard to find and/or implement)
then you'll have a simple calculation to do per frame.

[image]

with O being your camera.Position, C being your bounding sphere center, R the bounding sphere radius and D the distance you are searching.

You simply need to compute : D = O.DistanceTo(X) - R
So if you don't deform you mesh, the bounding sphere is computed on loading and wont change size. The D computation is pretty quick.

(Just for the sake of argument, this could produce non desirable effect if the mesh is very elongated in one dimension, like a long tube. -> the sphere would be very large then and from the side your object will not disapear at the right time)

Comment: Hi, TY for this reply. I had come up with a similar solution. It uses MathUtils.TryWorldToViewportTransform to project the widest points of the sphere as seen by the camera from 3D to 2D. If the 2D r-squared is below a threshold the sphere's transformation is adjusted so that the sphere stays at least at a minimum radius in the 2D projection. It compares using r-squared so that the SQRT calculation is made only if a size needs to be altered.